# Dimension of square rotated in 3D from projection on 2D

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I would like to track four points arranged as a square through 3D space.  The square can rotate freely in the three dimensions.  The example below left shows the square(blue) rotated 30 degrees about the x-axis, 60 degrees about the y-axis and 20-degrees about the z-axis.  On the right is what the camera sees.  The orange figure on left and right is the projection on xy plane.

To track the distance from camera, I need to know the dimensions of the blue square. We know everything about the orange figure, all angles and lengths. My problem is I can't make the connection to the blue square. I would appreciate some idea on how to calculate the blue square dimensions from knowing the orange angles and lengths.

[image: Left is square rotated with projection, Right is projection]

Here is the Python 2.7 code to generate the figure:

(the code has been updated to implement the answer)

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def show_the_rotated_square():
    #create the square in 2d with center at 0,0
    square_2D = [[-1, 1],[1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, -1]]

    #create a square in 3d so the square can be rotated in all three dimensions
    square_3D = [add_z(point) for point in square_2D]

    #create the three axis which the square will be rotated about
    axis = [[1, 0, 0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]

    X_ROTATE = 30
    Y_ROTATE = 60
    Z_ROTATE = 20

    #create a list of angles the square will be rotated for each axis
    theta = [np.radians(X_ROTATE),np.radians(Y_ROTATE),np.radians(Z_ROTATE)] 

    #rotate the 3d square about all three axis
    square_rotated_3D = rotate_point_list(square_3D,axis,theta)

    #create 2d version by removing z element
    square_rotated_2D = [remove_z(point) for point in square_rotated_3D]

#   print(angle_between_points(square_rotated_2D[0],square_rotated_2D[1],square_rotated_2D[2]))

    plot_3D(square_rotated_3D,121,"3D View, square rotated " + str(X_ROTATE) + " " + str(Y_ROTATE) + " " + str(Z_ROTATE),show_projection = True)
    plot_2D(square_rotated_2D,122,"Projection on XY plane (what camera sees)")

    solve(square_rotated_2D[0],square_rotated_2D[1],square_rotated_2D[3])
    solve(square_rotated_2D[1],square_rotated_2D[2],square_rotated_2D[0])
    solve(square_rotated_2D[2],square_rotated_2D[3],square_rotated_2D[1])
    solve(square_rotated_2D[3],square_rotated_2D[0],square_rotated_2D[2])

    plt.show()

#see math.stackexchange for discussion of solution
#https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879056/dimension-of-square-rotated-in-3d-from-projection-on-2d

def solve(pa,pb,pd):

    pb = pb - pa
    pd = pd - pa
    pa = pa - pa

    xb = pb[0]
    yb = pb[1]
    xd = pd[0]
    yd = pd[1]

    v = -(xb * xd + yb * yd)
    u = (xd**2 + yd**2) - (xb**2 + yb**2)

    a = 1
    b = -u
    c = -(v * v)

    #calculate discriminant
    d = b**2 - 4*a*c

    sol1 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2*a)
    sol2 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2*a)

    if (sol1>0):
        calc_square_side_length(sol1,v,xb,yb,xd,yd)
    if (sol2>0):
        calc_square_side_length(sol2,v,xb,yb,xd,yd)

def calc_square_side_length(s,v,xb,yb,xd,yd):
    b = math.sqrt(s)
    d = v / b

    ab = math.sqrt(xb**2 + yb**2)
    ad = math.sqrt(xd**2 + yd**2)

    ablen = math.sqrt(ab**2 + b**2)
    adlen = math.sqrt(ad**2 + d**2)

    print(ablen,adlen) # ablen and adlen should be same and be the side lengh of original 2d square, which is 2.0

#rotation_matrix code courtesy of:
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802577/rotation-of-3d-vector/12261243


def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac)],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab)],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc]])

def rotate_point_list(point_list,axis_list,theta_list):
    point_list_return = []
    for point in point_list:
    for axis,theta in zip(axis_list,theta_list):
        point = np.dot(rotation_matrix(axis,theta),point)
        point_list_return.append(point)

    return point_list_return

def angle_between_points(p1,p2,p3):
    v0 = p1 - p2
    v1 = p3 - p2

    angle = np.math.atan2(np.linalg.det([v0,v1]),np.dot(v0,v1))
    return np.degrees(angle)

def plot_3D(square,arrangement,title='',show_projection = False):
    x = [point[0] for point in square]
    y = [point[1] for point in square]
    z = [point[2] for point in square]
    x.append(x[0])
    y.append(y[0])
    z.append(z[0])

    sa = fig.add_subplot(arrangement, projection='3d')
    sa.plot(x,y,z,color="darkblue")

    if show_projection is True:
        colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00","#0000FF","#000000"]
        for xx,yy,zz,cc in zip(x,y,z,colors):
            sa.scatter(xx,yy,zz,color=cc)
            xl = []
            xl.append(xx)
            xl.append(xx)
            yl = []
            yl.append(yy)
            yl.append(yy)
            zl = []
            zl.append(zz)
            zl.append(0)
            sa.plot(xl,yl,zl,color = cc)

        z = [0 for point in x]
        sa.plot(x,y,z,color="orange")

    AXIS_LIM = 2

    sa.set_xlabel('X')
    sa.set_ylabel('Y')
    sa.set_zlabel('Z')
    sa.set_xlim(-AXIS_LIM,AXIS_LIM)
    sa.set_ylim(-AXIS_LIM,AXIS_LIM)
    sa.set_zlim(-AXIS_LIM,AXIS_LIM)
    sa.set_title(title)


def plot_2D(square,arrangement,title='',color = 'darkorange'):
    x = [point[0] for point in square]
    y = [point[1] for point in square]
    x.append(x[0])
    y.append(y[0])
    sa = fig.add_subplot(arrangement)
    sa.plot(x,y,color = color)
    colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00","#0000FF","#000000"]
    for xx,yy,cc in zip(x,y,colors):
        sa.scatter(xx,yy,color=cc)

    AXIS_LIM = 2


    sa.set_xlabel('X')
    sa.set_ylabel('Y')
    sa.set_xlim(-AXIS_LIM,AXIS_LIM)
    sa.set_ylim(-AXIS_LIM,AXIS_LIM)
    sa.set_title(title)

def remove_z(point):
    return np.delete(point,2)

def add_z(point):
    return np.append(point,0)

fig = plt.figure()


show_the_rotated_square()
```

Comment: If you only have the projection, it would  be impossible, since there are infinitely many 3D objects with the same 2D projection.

Comment: @xbh I make an objection to your objection : "infinitely many objects" yes, but you have to take into account the fact that you know the object you are looking for : it has to be a square ; thus, the solution is (almost) unique up to a vertical translation and a symmetry vs. an horizontal plane

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, i missed this point. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $ABCD$ (named counterclockwise) the ''orange'' parallelogram (see figure below). Consider the prismatic volume $V$ (with four vertical sides) intersecting the horizontal plane along this parallelogram. Up to a translation, one can assume that the coordinates of our points are : 
$$A(0,0,0),B(x_B,y_B,0),D(x_D,y_D,0),B'(x_B,y_B,b),D'(x_D,y_D,d)$$
with unknowns $b$ and $d$ (positive or negative).

The constraints are

$$(1) \ \ \|\overrightarrow{AB'}\|^2=\|\overrightarrow{AD'}\|^2 \ \ \text{(same - squared - lengths) and}$$

$$(2) \ \ \overrightarrow{AB'}.\overrightarrow{AD'}=0 \ \ \text{(orthogonality).}$$

(dot product = 0 means orthogonality)

(1) becomes : $(1') \ \ (x_B^2+y_B^2)+b^2=(x_D^2+y_D^2)+d^2.$

and (2) becomes $ (2') \ \ x_Bx_D+y_By_D+bd=0.$

(classical formula for dot product).

System (1')+(2') of two equations with two unknowns is rather easy to solve. Here is how. Let us write it under the form :

$$b^2-d^2=u \ \ \text{and} \ \ bd=v$$

$u$ and $v$ being constants.

Let us plug $d=\dfrac{v}{b}$ (we can assume WLOG that $b \neq 0$) into the first equation, giving $b^2-\dfrac{v^2}{b^2}=u$ ; set  $\beta=b^2$ yielding $\beta-\dfrac{v^2}{\beta}=u$, i.e., a quadratic equation that we solve for $\beta$ ; we then take (plus or minus) its square root to get $b$, out of which we deduce the other unknown $d=\dfrac{v}{b}$.

One can wonder what happens if $\beta$ is negative (square root of a negative number...). This case should never happen, first of all because parallelogram $ABCD$  comes from a ''real'' (with quotes !) projection of a ''real'' square that our equations must find out. But also for a theoretical reason that I have not the time now to write down in detail.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm not much of a mathematician and will do my best to understand and code the solution.

Comment: I have modified/simplified my answer. Moreover, I have provided a figure.

Comment: I have a question : do you know $L$ beforehand ? Or must you deduce it from the projection ? (in such a case, what I have called a verification will become another equation...)

Comment: I was about to ask you this.  We must deduce the length L from projection.  We will use the length L in a calibrated way to deduce the distance from the camera.

Comment: Thus I am going to rewrite my solution...

Comment: Solution completely updated.

Comment: Are you assuming the lengths AB and AD are the same?  The equation (1) seems to say so to my untrained eye.   AB and DC are equal and AD and BC are equal

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten the "primes". I correct it.

Comment: Correction done.

Comment: The interior angles of the orange parallelogram don't seem to be required for the solution.  Is this reasonable?

Comment: In fact they are implicitly required by the fact that we need the coordinates of $B$ and $D$ (with respect to $A$)

Comment: I have implemented the answer in the updated python code.  The answer works on all four corners.  I may give a triangle a try at some point.

Comment: Happy it works well. But I don't understand the meaning of your last sentence.

Comment: Instead of using 4 points arranged in a square, use 3 points arranged in an equilateral triangle. Equation (2) would use dot product for 60 degree angle.